# Puppeteer - The webpage I am scraping isnt displaying the correct data

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrap class availability on my colleges website using puppeteer. I successfully did it with selenium but I am having trouble with puppeteer. When I click enter on the form, the next page is blank regardless of what I input.

[what it shows when i browse myself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaTGH.png)

[what it shows when i use puppeteer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TerzI.png)

Heres the code I used, it just opens the website, selects the semester and class number and presses enter:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
async function start() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false})
    var [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto("https://usfweb.usf.edu/DSS/StaffScheduleSearch")
    await page.select('#P_SEMESTER', "202208")
    await page.type("#P_REF", "81151")
    await page.click("button[value='Search']")
}
start()
```

It works in selenium, and i tried opening the website on chromium and it works there to.
Thank you to anyone who gives advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and the output was exactly the same as what you were seeing in the browser
everything all right
[image: i]Chromium or puppeteer versions are probably not compatible with each other

puppeteer Version : "^16.1.0"
chrome version : Version 104.0.5112.81

Comment: Thank you this worked! My chromium was on version 106. It took a while but I managed to find the correct chromium version and replace the files.